# Add metadata via REST API Call in Alfresco Community

Tags: rest, metadata, alfresco, alfresco-maven

Is it possible to add different metadata to a document via rest call?

thank you

I tried to upload a document to alfresco using rest call but now i want to add some metadata to that document and search for it by its properties.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using, and how are you uploading the document - public REST API, CMIS, internal REST API, other?

Comment: I'm using the last version of alfresco community 7.4.0, to upload the document I'm using the public REST API  «ACS REST API».

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not send all the metadata at the same time as the upload? [The create child node API takes metadata as well!](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/?urls.primaryName=Core%20API#/nodes/createNode)

Comment: Yes, thank you @Gagravarr this is really helpful. But now in case, I want to create a new model with a specific type using only remote API (CMIS, REST) how can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try following https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.2/config/models/ ?

Comment: Hi again, Yes, but this method shows only how to manage custom models in Alfresco Share using the Model Manager. What I want now is to manage the model via CMIS/REST.

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/add-custom-metadata-with-new-file-upload/m-p/301378#M20931) but I'm not really sure about it. It consists to upload the model to the alfresco models repository. I've uploaded my XML model to Models and I can see it there but not in model manager.